# How to write regular expression in nutch?

Tags: regex, nutch

I am using Nutch for crawling web pages. I am getting problem in writing the regular expression.

It is working fine with the following configuration:
Seed url :
www.practo.com 
(preceded with https:// )

Regex-urlfilter.txt: 
+^https://www.practo.com/

But I want to fetch only specific pages such as pages that contain information about 'cardiologist'
Example: I want to fetch pages like:
www.practo.com/hyderabad/doctor/some-name-cardiologist
i.e. I want to fetch pages ending in certain keyword.

I am using following regular expression:
+^https://www.practo.com(/[a-z0-9]*)*cardiologist

Please help me out in writing the regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer to my question. Problem was getting the correct regular expression.

+^(https|http)://([a-zA-Z0-9./-]+)cardiologist([a-zA-Z0-9-#?=])*

The following site help me a lot to get to the correct expression : https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

You ca use the following:

```
+^https://www\.practo\.com.*cardiologist
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not working.
Following error message is comming:
 
Stopping at depth=0 - no more URLs to fetch.
No URLs to fetch - check your seed list and URL filters.
crawl finished: cardio